# Issue with RTL languages in android

Tags: android, unicode, textview, arabic, right-to-left

I have a problem with right-to-left languages in TextView. When I write in Arabic, the characters appear separately. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Note that Android did not support RTL languages until Android 2.3, and we have been told that better RTL support will come in Android 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no encouraging answer. There are two problems: fonts and text layout. I believe that the fonts in Android don't come with tables for Arabic ligatures and letter shaping. Furthermore, as far as I can tell, the layout engine (android.text.Layout and related classes) do not know know how to handle bidirectional text properly. Although this is supposedly in the works, my guess is that it will be some time before an Android release handles rtl languages properly, and even more time before a significant fraction of actual devices will do so.

Answer (score 1):

You should get good arabic **font** and use **reshaper**.Link for arabic reshaper [Arabic reshaper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/)